# Using SQL Alchemy to Import Data and Replace Given a Condition

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, selenium, sqlalchemy

Below is the last part of my selenium web scraper that loops through the different tabs of this [website page](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=y&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0), selects the "export data" button, downloads the data, adds a "yearid" column, then loads the data into a MySQL table.

```
    df = pd.read_csv(desired_filepath)
    df["yearid"] = datetime.today().year
    df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('%')]] = \
    (df.filter(regex='%')
     .apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace(r'[\s%]', ''),
                                    errors='coerce')))
    df.to_csv(desired_filepath)

    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                           .format(user="walker",
                                   pw="password",
                                   db="data"))
    df.to_sql(con=engine, name='fg_test_hitting_{}'.format(button_text), if_exists='replace')

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Everything works great, but I would like to import the data into the MySQL table and replace only if the yearid=2018. Does anyone know if it is possible to load data and replace given a specific condition? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just filter the subset of data before loading it into mysql? Something like `df[df['yearid']==2018].to_sql(...)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't because the current table has multiple years of data. The scraper only pulls data one year at a time, so when it replaces, it will delete the other years of data and I would just be stuck with 2018 data.

Comment: try `if_exists='append'`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Unfortunately, I can't do that either because the data I am pulling are baseball season totals. If I appended, I would have a DB full of multiple season totals for every player. I need to replace each row that has yearid=2018 so each player has one season total for that specific year.

Comment: Are you generating this DB solely off this scraping 'session'? If so, you can concatenate a single df from all of the yearly dfs, filter for whatever you want (sounds like latest year of data for each player), and do a single `to_sql` call.

Comment: I am not. Right now I have two sets of code to scrape that data. One for the current year, and the other for past years. I am trying to figure out the best way to aggregate all the years in one table while also updating the current year on a daily basis without having to eliminate the past years' data. Thanks again for the advice!

Comment: One approach could be to first put in all of previous years' data. Then have your update process do the following: 1) Delete all of 2018 data, 2) recreate updated 2018 data, and 3) put updated 2018 data back in with `if_exists='append'`.

Comment: That's essentially what I am trying to do, I just need to figure out how to do it in the framework of my scraper. I have a table that has all non-2018 data, but if I do a `if_exists='append'` I can't update it on a daily basis because each player will have multiple total rows. If I use `if_exists='replace'`, then the whole table becomes a 2018 data. I need to figure out a way to fit step 1 (delete all of 2018 data) within the automation process of my scraper.

Comment: maybe run something like `engine.execute('DELETE FROM fg_test_hitting_{} WHERE yearid = 2018'.format(button_text))` before you append the new 2018 data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rather than deleting from your table it may be better to just let MySQL handle the replacing. You can do this by creating a temporary table with the new data, replace into the permanent table, then delete the temp table. The big caveat here is that you will need to set the keys in your table (Ideally only once). I don't know what your key fields are so its tough to help in this regard.

Replace the commented line with this:

```
# df.to_sql(con=engine, name='fg_test_hitting_{}'.format(button_text), if_exists='replace')
conn = engine.connect()

# should fail if temporary table already exists (we want it to fail in this case)
df.to_sql('fg_test_hitting_{}_tmp'.format(button_text), conn)

# Will create the permanent table if it does not already exist (will only matter in the first run)
# note that you may have to create keys here so that mysql knows what constitutes a replacement
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fg_test_hitting_{} LIKE fg_test_hitting_{}_tmp;'.format(button_text, button_text))

# updating the permanent table and dropping the temporary table
conn.execute('REPLACE INTO fg_test_hitting_{} (SELECT * FROM fg_test_hitting_{}_tmp);'.format(button_text, button_text))
conn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fg_test_hitting_{}_tmp;'.format(button_text))
```

Comment: Let me see if I am understanding your logic. You create a temp table with all of the updated 2018 data, then take all the data in the temp table and insert it into my permanent table with the multiple years of data (i.e. 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), then delete the temp table. How would the code above know to delete the old 2018 data, then replace it with the new 2018 data in the permanent table? Thanks again for the detailed response! Really appreciate the insight!

Comment: It would know what to replace with what based on the keys you assign. So say there is already a row with some data for Bob-2018. If a new row of data for Bob-2018 is `REPLACE INTO` the table, it will overwrite the existing row rather than creating a new row. Its probably out of the scope of this question to explain how keys work - the main point is that there can only be one row per key. So there cannot be more than one row for Bob-2018 in that table ever. Best practice is to control those structures in the DB rather than the inputting code.

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification! Each player has his own 'playerid' and I can assign that as the primary key so the overwrite should work. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. If you found that this addressed your question, please feel free to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As described by @Leo in comments first delete that part of data (from MySQL table) that you were going to update and then save it to MySQL table:

```
conn = engine.connect()
cur = conn.cursor()
...

cur.execute('delete from fg_test_hitting_{} where yearid=?'.format(button_text), 
            (pd.datetime.today().year,))

df.to_sql(con=engine, name='fg_test_hitting_{}'.format(button_text), if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Thanks MaxU! This worked great. For some reason, the cursor wouldn't connect to MySQL, but I changed `cur.execute` to `conn.execute` and deleted `pd.datetime.today().year` and that seemed to work. Thanks again!